# Path of all possible lengths $1, \ldots n - 2$ on $(n - 1)$-cycle

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinations

There is cycle with $n - 1$ vertices. $\ge \frac{n}{2}$ vertices are selected. Prove that paths of all the possible lengths from $1, 2, \ldots, n - 2$ can be drawn between selected vertices.

It is easy to see that paths with lenghts $1$ and $n - 2$ can be drawn but what about possibility to draw path of arbitrary length $k$, $1 \le k \le n - 2$?

This is part of some other proof.

Comment: This is your 11th question and you've accepted none of the answers given to you. Maybe you've only been received bad or no answers, but I, for one, will not bother answering this question since I can see there is little hope of being rewarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following.

Enumerate the vertices along the cycle by residues $\mod n-1$. Fix the number $k$. The vertices $v_i$ and $v_j$ we call equivalent, provided $i-j\in k\Bbb Z_{n-1}$. Then the sets of the vertices of the cycle is partitioned into equivalency classes. Since the quantity of selected vertices is larger than a half of the quantity of all vertices, there is an equivalency class $C$ in which the quantity of selected vertices is larger than a half of the quantity of all vertices. Pick an arbitrary vertex $v_i\in C$. Imagine the class $C$ as a cyclic sequence $v_i-v_{i+k}-v_{i+2k}-\dots-v_{i-k}-v_i$. Since in $C$ the quantity of selected vertices is larger than a half of the quantity of all vertices, there exists a number $l$ such that both vertices $v_{i+lk}$ and $v_{i+(l+1)k}$ are selected. Then the path between these vertices has length $k$.

Comment: It would be improvement to this answer if the phrase "of all vertices" would be more specific and more clear "of all vertices in the congruence class" in some places. But otherwise - thanks!